# Excel file name changed dynamically

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, command

I used an excel template. In my ssis package at first the template is copied in the working directory and package execute. In the next run the excel file which is already existed in the working directory it moved into BACKUP folder and again the template file copied. It works good.

But i want to do something when i move it i want to rename it like is the previous file name is Input_01 in the next move it will input_02. How can i do this?
i am using ***Execute process task*** toolbox in SSIS pacakge.

and a .bat file is called. in the .bat file i write

```
         move "E:\InputFolder\Input.xls" "D:\Backup"

         copy "E:\Template\Input.xls" "E:\InputFolder\Input.xls"
```

I want a ouput in the backup folder the excel files are like

Input_01,Input_02.... what will be my command?

Comment: What would happen if you added a file name to the move command?

Comment: if i added a file name like D:\Backup\input_01 then alltym it move the Input file to the backup folder with a named input_01.xls
but i want in the next run it will convert input_02 automatically.

Comment: Are you open to having a date appended in the name like input_20140521 instead of the 01, 02 ? I ask this because it we wont be able to guess which no. the file is unless you iterate through the files already in the back up folder or store your current number (01, 02, 03 etc) in the database.

Comment: Instead of bat file, you probably are better off using File System Task within SSIS, and passing the file name in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with a batch file:

```
@echo off
set cnt=1
for /f %%f in ('dir /b "D:\Backup\Input_*.xls"') do set /a cnt+=1
if %cnt% lss 10 (move "E:\InputFolder\Input.xls" "D:\Backup\Input_0%cnt%.xls") else (move "E:\InputFolder\Input.xls" "D:\Backup\Input_%cnt%.xls")
copy "E:\Template\Input.xls" "E:\InputFolder\Input.xls"
```

You can have more control over your files' naming convention (not to mention deletion of old files) if you use a Script Task, though.

Answer (score 0):

can we use a 'File system task' instead. It helps us Renaming a file. You will have to use a 'For-Each loop Container' as well.

[image]